# Unnesting values in records in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have been tasked to unnest records in `MongoDB`, but I have no `MongoDB` skills, unfortunately.

I have records in the following format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("Some ID"),
    "reason" : "Parameter: (artifact_id) is mandatory",
    "timestamp_utc" : ISODate("2019-09-20T14:30:41.943Z"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-20T07:30:41.943Z"),
    "eventType" : "Some_Event",
    "clientID" : "24839961",
    "time_bucket" : [
        "2019-year",
        "2019-09-month",
        "2019-37-week",
        "2019-09-20-day",
        "2019-09-20 07-hour"
    ],
    "payload" : {
        "resWidth" : 1440,
        "resHeight" : 900,
        "device" : "",
        "context_eid" : "Some EID",
        "artifact_revision_id" : 8389171,
        "page_url" : "Some URL",
        "client_ip" : "Some IP",
        "tz" : "Asia/Calcutta",
        "memberID" : Some_ID,
        "url_referrer" : "Some_URL",
        "tabID" : "Some ID",
        "artifactID" : 5665946,
        "visitorID" : "Some ID",
        "g_event_id" : "Some ID",
        "content_data" : "Some Data",
        "sessionID" : "Some ID",
        "user_agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
    },
    "resolved" : false
}
```

Notice that `payload` is it's own dictionary. I have to unnest that dictionary and bring it back to the same level as the other keys in the document. Like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("Some ID"),
    "reason" : "Parameter: (artifact_id) is mandatory",
    "timestamp_utc" : ISODate("2019-09-20T14:30:41.943Z"),
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-20T07:30:41.943Z"),
    "eventType" : "Some_Event",
    "clientID" : "24839961",
    "time_bucket" : [
        "2019-year",
        "2019-09-month",
        "2019-37-week",
        "2019-09-20-day",
        "2019-09-20 07-hour"
    ],
    "resWidth" : 1440,
    "resHeight" : 900,
    "device" : "",
    "context_eid" : "Some EID",
    "artifact_revision_id" : 8389171,
    "page_url" : "Some URL",
    "client_ip" : "Some IP",
    "tz" : "Asia/Calcutta",
    "memberID" : Some_ID,
    "url_referrer" : "Some_URL",
    "tabID" : "Some ID",
    "artifactID" : 5665946,
    "visitorID" : "Some ID",
    "g_event_id" : "Some ID",
    "content_data" : "Some Data",
    "sessionID" : "Some ID",
    "user_agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36",
    "resolved" : false
}
```

My initial research says `$reduce` could be an option, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help on this subject would be appreciated. I'm sorry if this task is too simple to be posting for, but I have zero `MongoDB` skills.

Comment: Just a note, you have fields `timestamp_utc` and `timestamp`, however `Z` at the end of ISO formatted date/time string indicates UTC time. I assume `timestamp` shall be **local** time but value has wrong time zone.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks so much for pointing that out. I will look into this.

Comment: Library [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) may help you to generate and manipulate DATE/TIME values.

Comment: `Date` values in MongoDB are always stored in UTC. Typically the client converts them to local time and also formats it. In shell you could use for example `{
    $addFields: {
      timestamp_local: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: "$timestamp_utc",
          format: "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S",
          timezone: "$tz"
        }
      }
    }
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a Mongo version smaller than 4.2 then you cant update a documents using its own values, meaning you have to read the document and then re-save it.
The data restructuring can happen both in Mongo or code.

Heres a quick example using js:

```
db.EVENT_NAME.find().map(function(u) {
    let newDoc = Object.assign(u, u.payload);
    delete newDoc.payload;
    return db.EVENT_NAME.findOneAndReplace({_id: newDoc._id}, {$set: newDoc})
} );
```

However introduced in Mongo 4.2 [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2/#availability), Meaning now you can do all of this in one command:

```
db.EVENT_NAME.updateMany({},
    [
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot:
                    {$mergeObjects: ["$payload", "$$ROOT"]}
            }
        },
        {$unset: "payload"}
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). If we merge top-level document (`$$ROOT` variable) with `payload` object, we get single object (`$mergeObjects` should be assigned into new variable, but we reduce pipeline steps doing 2 operation in one with `$ReplaceRoot` or `$ReplaceWith`).

```
db.EVENT_NAME.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          "$payload"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "payload"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ozbTP-DndZZ)